# View not always showing all the column values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I hope I am posting this in the right spot.

We are in the process of moving from DB2 to SQL Server 2016.  In a test environment, we have moved all the data, modified most of the views, functions, procedures, etc.

I was going through testing various reports.  Had to make the necessary changes to get reports to run (i.e. date commands, concatenation, etc).  While testing the changes to a query, the first time I ran it, no results were returned, nor was there an error.  I ran the query again and I received a results set.  I didn't think much of it until I was working on another query.  I ran it one time and some of the columns did not have any data.  Running it again, the data might be there, it might not.  Sometimes I could run it 5 times in a row and every time data was missing.  Other times I could run it 5 times in a row and the data was there.  It was always the same columns that were missing data (and it was the entire column).

The original query was joining a view to some tables.  So, I simplified it to just the view.  I saw the same.  Sometimes the data was there and sometimes it wasn't.

The view is created for a common table expression.  Basically, there are about 5 or so CTEs that are pulling only the current rows from 5 different tables.  The CTEs are then later left outer joined to a master table (which is also inner joined to some type tables).  The data from the master table and type tables are always there.  It is the CTEs that seem to be missing.  However, one of the CTEs is also always there.

Has anyone seen this behavior? I just trimmed down the view to only have one CTE and just the main table.  The following is the view and the SQL statement.  This simplified view does give the same results as the more complicated one.  I always get a row with the first three columns populated, and then sometimes the rest of the columns are populated and sometimes they are null.  I also ran a query against the contact.contact_list table looking for the same ID.  I ran it many, many times and it always brought back the row.

```
CREATE VIEW CONTACT.ANTOXCUST2 (
   clinicid, 
   clinicname, 
   address1, 
   address2, 
   city, 
   stateabrv, 
   countryid, 
   postalcode
)
AS 
   WITH 
      addr AS 
      (
         SELECT 
            ADDRESS.ADDRESS_ID, 
            ADDRESS.CONTACT_ID, 
            ADDRESS.ADDRESS_1, 
            ADDRESS.ADDRESS_2, 
            ADDRESS.CITY, 
            ADDRESS.STATE_ABRV, 
            ADDRESS.COUNTRY_ID, 
            ADDRESS.POSTAL_CODE 
         FROM CONTACT.ADDRESS
         WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE_ID = 1 AND getdate() <= coalesce(ADDRESS.EXPIRATION_DATE, getdate())
      )

      SELECT 
         cl.CONTACT_ID, 
         coalesce(cl.CONTACT_NAME, ' '), 
         a.ADDRESS_1, 
         a.ADDRESS_2, 
         a.CITY, 
         a.STATE_ABRV, 
         a.COUNTRY_ID, 
         a.POSTAL_CODE
      FROM 
         CONTACT.CONTACT_LIST  AS cl 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN addr  AS a 
            ON cl.CONTACT_ID = a.CONTACT_ID;

---------------------------------------------------
select *
from   contact.antoxcust2 ac
where  ac.clinicid = 4678
```

Comment: Data in SQL Server does not just show up in a result set in one query and then not in a subsequent query without something acting on either the data or the query itself. If your query is running the EXACT same way (same view, same WHERE clause, etc) then the next logical thing is that some external force is acting on the data.

Comment: Doing a little more research, it looks like it has something to do with the getdate() <= coalesce(ADDRESS.EXPIRATION_DATE, getdate()).  If I hard code a date instead of the getdate(), it doesn't seem to fail.  I was thinking that maybe the two getdate() are getting two different timestamps.  However, I created another CTE that just selects getdate() and then used that value in place of the other two.  It still fails.

Comment: Hard code a big date for the second?

Comment: @Paparazzi The issue with adding a bid date for the second date is that there could be a row that has an expiration date set to the end of the month and another row that starts the first of next month and does not have an expiration date.  Setting a big date in the coalesce would then bring back two rows.  Your other solutions seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE ADDRESS.ADDRESS_TYPE_ID = 1 
  AND (ADDRESS.EXPIRATION_DATE is null OR getdate() <= ADDRESS.EXPIRATION_DATE)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate your answer?

Comment: @eden One call to getdate()

Comment: @Paparazzi that seems to work.  Any idea why? I see you told eden that it is one call to getdate().  However, I tried creating an additional CTE that would just select getdate().  I then joined it to the contact.address table in the addr CTE.  I then had mydate <= coalesce(address.expiration_date,mydate) and it still didn't always work.  Wouldn't that have only been a single call to getdate() since it was happening in an earlier CTE? Are there issues with coalesce in SQL Server? I also tried the ISNULL() function and still had issues.

Comment: @DLuchin If it works you could select the check mark.

Comment: I would use declare @Today datetime = getdate(), then use '@Today' in place of any getdate().  This makes sure getdate is called only once, and all values are exactly the same.  

Although, SQL may be smart enough now to do that when optimized.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, the first thing I'd try is to cast the GetDates as dates as below:

```
CAST(GetDate() AS date)
```

That removes the possibility that the GetDate() functions are returning ever so slightly different values.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  However, I should have stated that the EXPIRATION_DATE was actually a timestamp.